# How to query a complex nested objects in Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I have several entities that you can see below, the problem is how to select nested lists properly when you have more than one level of nesting. If you take a look at Google repository on [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample), you can find very simple example, but not something complex. As documentation says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data.html#understand-no-object-references), Room doesn't allow object references. How to get `ResultObject` (and how it should look) including all nested lists?

ResultObject should have this info:

1. `List<Dialog>`
2. `Dialog` entity has `List<Message>`.
3. `Message` has `List<ImageContent>`.
4. `ImageContent` has `List<ImageContentItem>`

Dialog

```
@Entity(tableName = "dialog")
data class Dialog(@PrimaryKey val id String, val title: String)
```

Message

```
@Entity(tableName = "message",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = Dialog::class, parentColumns ["id"], childColumns = ["dialogId"]))])
data class Message(@PrimaryKey val id: String, val dialogId: String)
```

ImageContent

```
@Entity(tableName = "image_content",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = Message::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["messageId"]))])
data class ImageContent(@PrimaryKey val id: String, val messageId: String)
```

ImageContentItem

```
@Entity(tableName = "image_content_item",
        foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(entity = ImageContent::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["imageContentId"]))])
data class ImageContentItem(val imageContentId: String,
                        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 1)
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface DialogDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dialog " +
            "INNER JOIN message ON message.dialogId = dialog.id " +
            "INNER JOIN image_content ON image_content.messageId = message.id " +
            "INNER JOIN image_content_item ON image_content_item.imageContentId = image_content.id")
    fun getDialogAllInformation(): Flowable<List<**ResultObject**>>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rooms works with entity/table and it does not allow to manage structured object like you needed. The only thing you can do is execute queries separately and then build your `ResultObject`.

Answer (score 32):

You can nest classes defining relationships as much as you want.

```
class DeepDialog {
    @Embedded lateinit var embedded: Dialog

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dialogId", entity = Message::class)
    lateinit var messages: List<DeepMessage>
}

class DeepMessage {
    @Embedded lateinit var embedded: Message    

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "messageId", entity = ImageContent::class)
    lateinit var imageContents: List<DeepImageContent>
}

... etc
```

I think Room guys should come with something more elegant as this solution has at least two issues.

1. It introduces quite annoying boilerplate.
2. `@Relation` annotation can be used only on Lists or Sets so it doesn't cover scenarios where you have 1:1 relationship.

Imagine your `Dialog` would have only one `Message` by definition (instead of many). In that case, you wouldn't want your `DeepDialog` to have `messages: List<>` accessor but `message: Message` instead. The only way around I found is:

```
class DeepDialog {
    @Embedded lateinit var embedded: Dialog

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dialogId", entity = Message::class)
    internal lateinit var messages: List<DeepMessage>
    val message get() = messages.firstOrNull()
}
```

Comment: `I think Room guys should come with something more elegant as this solution has at least two issues.` EXACTLY!

Comment: How would one construct the query in the DAO to retrieve this data? 

`@Transaction
@Query("SELECT *, * FROM dialog, message WHERE dialog.id = message.dialogId")
fun allDeepDialogs(): LiveData<List<DeepDialog>>` doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: So... does this work? I've been trying to do something similar but I get a `Cannot find the parent entity column` error